# Going from AVL trees to Red-Black trees

Tags: avl-tree, red-black-tree, 2-3-4-tree

According to my book, coloring red links that go from nodes of even height to nodes of odd height in an AVL tree gives a (perfectly balanced) 2-3-4 tree, where red links are not necessarily left-leaning. 
But I don't get how exactly. When I try it with some examples, I keep getting stuck. Can someone illustrate it for me please?